# Can I configure laravel homestead using specific versions of software? Particularly, downgrade mariadb version

Tags: laravel, vagrant, mariadb, homestead

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I have installed "laravel/homestead": "^9.0". Homestead comes with MariaDB 10.4.8. But my hosting has MariaDB version 10.1.39 and looks like a can't change it. So I need downgrade my Homestead version of MariaDB to develop using same versions of software.

I have tried set MariaDB version in Homestead.yaml like this and 'vagrant up':

```
    features:
        - mariadb: 
            version: 10.1.39
```

But version had not changed.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular, nobody here knows your setup. As a new user, also take the [tour] for introduction.

Comment: Remember to run `vagrant --provision` if you change the Homestead.yaml file.